# Is $\pi/e$ a period?

Tags: definite-integrals, algebraic-number-theory

Is $\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{e}$ a period?

[This was inspired by question [Is there a non-trivial definite integral that values to $\frac{e}{\pi}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2958600/442) ]

By a [**period**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_periods) I mean

> a number that can be expressed as an integral of an algebraic function over an algebraic domain

See [What is ... a period](https://www.ams.org/notices/201408/rnoti-p898.pdf)

> An **algebraic domain** is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ given by polynomial inequalities with rational coefficients.

The **algebraic function** should be a solution of a polynomial equation with integer coefficients.  Increasing the dimension by one, we may as well assume the integrand is a rational function with integer coefficients.

We know that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1} \, \text{dx} = \frac{\pi}{e}
$$

And it is a mysterious fact that many integrals involving elementary functions are periods.  What about this one?

[The problem cited goes on to ask about a "simple integral" with result $e/\pi$ as well.  Presumably $e/\pi$ is not a period, since $\pi$ is a period, and the product $(e/\pi)\;\pi = e$ is conjecturally not a period.]

Comment: If $\pi$ is a period then what algebraic function integrates definitely to give $\pi$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire $\int_{x^2+y^2 \le 1} dx dy =  \pi$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: To get $\pi$, integrate the algebraic function $1$ on the algebraic domain: unit disk.

Comment: Btw the page you linked is a Page Non Trouvée

Comment: @TheSimpliFire If you like, partially integrate Najib's example to give the single-variable integral $\pi = \int_{-1}^1 2 \sqrt{1 - x^2} dx$.

Comment: What is an algebraic domain?

Comment: OK different reference put in.

Comment: Is $1 / \pi$ even a period? If so, then $\pi / e$ being a period would imply $1 / e$ being a period, which you might expect not to be true on similar grounds as the fact that $e$ is suspected not to be one.

Comment: @Sofie: It is conjectured that $1/\pi$ is not a period.

Comment: Most likely, not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is expected that $\pi/e$ is not a period, but this is not known, and in general it is very difficult to prove that a number is not a period.

In the paper [Exponential motives](http://javier.fresan.perso.math.cnrs.fr/expmot.pdf), Fresán and Jossen formulate a version of the Grothendieck period conjecture for certain integrals involving $e$, and Propsition 12.1.4 says that their conjecture implies that $e$ is transcendental over the ring of periods. In particular, since $\pi$ is a period, their conjecture would imply that $\pi/e$ is not a period.